# Why do I have to Force Quit finder to see my new screenshot files?

Tags: finder, folders

On my mac mini (OS X 10.9.5), I have to `Force Quit` Finder in order to see the screenshot jpgs in my `/screenshots` folder I literally *just* took a millisecond ago.  Even if I wait a few minutes, I won't see the screenshot jpgs  in my folder until I `Force Quit`.

Why is this?

UPDATE: After waiting a couple hours without `Force Quit`, I now see the screenshot jpgs.

Why can't I see the screenshot jpgs instantly like I do on other macs?

**UPDATE #2: Updating to Yosemite has solved this issue.**

Comment: What do you mean "see"? The screen shots are automatically saved in the folder of your choosing. To see them open the file.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Clarified that I don't see the screenshot jpgs.

Comment: Sorry more questions for clarity. Do you use sharing, do you use iCloud or Time machine that would potentially explain that? Do you have some virus scanner? Next we will look in to resetting your Finder app.

Comment: I don't use any of those on my mac mini.  I just repaired `Disk Permissions` to see if that would help.  Didn't help.

Comment: Perhaps the Finder does not update it's database as often as it should - maybe putting the screenshots in ~/Desktop/screenshots or ~/Documents/screenshots would get the update happening quicker? Have you tried Onyx to delete/rebuild the various system caches and databases?

Comment: @j-beda I already put them in `/Documents/Screenshots`. I used Onyx to delete/rebuild the system caches and the issue is still there.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Buscar웃  Is resetting the Finder app different than what Onyx does?

Comment: I would not know, but still confused, after taking a screenshot does the file shows in the designated folder? I would try to change the location for screenshots files.in Termoinal "defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/[u]/Pictures/Screenshots/" Replace "[u]" with the name of the user on your system. Once you have entered this command, let's restart the screen capture utility by restarting the SystemUIServer by entering the following command:

"killall SystemUIServer"

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks for the commands.  Still doesn't work. The screenshot jpgs show up in the correct folder only *after* I `Force Quit > Relaunch` Finder

Comment: Finder updates went from synchronous to asynchronous several versions back (Snow Leopard?), when Apple started getting serious about dealing with networked drives. Those can be slow, but unfortunately Apple never upped refresh priority for local storage. Rebooting Finder, or changing views can give the process a nudge.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Thanks for the info. Hopefully this is fixed in Yosemite now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I found on StackOverflow [Automator Command to Refresh ALL Finder Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788558/automator-command-to-refresh-all-finder-all-finder-windows)
Make it into an applescript application.

btw, you don't need to force-quit the finder, you can relaunch it gracefully if you Opt/right click or Ctrl/Opt/left click on the icon in the dock.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat  
end tell
```

Comment: `option + left click` to relaunch Finder is the only solution that works for me.  Yours is closest answer.